# 3-way switch not working properly: why will one switch not turn off the light?

Tags: wiring

I wired this setup approximately 15 years ago. It worked perfectly, it’s in the master bath.

I changed a single light switch in the bedroom, a regular black white and ground. After that, the 3-way in the bathroom isn’t working properly.

I can turn the bathroom light on from either switch but the opposite switch won’t turn the light off. I’m baffled. Any ideas?

Comment: So you didn't change one of the three way switches?  You changed _only_ a light switch in an adjacent room?  You didn't change any light fixtures or outlets?

Comment: When you changed the switch, did you happen to change it to an actively powered switch of some kind? Smart switch, dimmer, etc.?

Comment: The light switch was for a light on a ceiling fan. The fan works independently from the light, the fan works. I bought a new light kit thinking the ballast in the light is shot. I’ll install the light kit later today. Other than that no 3 way switches were touched.